# How to use the output that is printed by a method in the main class?

Tags: java, arrays, string, methods

I'm working on a word search project, this program gets a text file as an input, the first method `scanVocabulary` creates an array of the first 3000 words in the text. The second method `printWords` gets the output of `scanVocabulary` and three letters, it returns the words that include the 3 letters in the order they were inserted.

When I run my program, I can tell that `scanVocabulary` works, because I get the correct length of the text I inserted, but when I run `printWords` I don't get an output at all.

My methods are supposed to print the output and not return it. So how am I supposed to get the output?

I think the problem is in the main method.

This is my code:

```
    package sw1.ex4;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class WordSearch {
    public static String[] scanVocabulary(Scanner scanner) {

        int counter = 0;
        String[] result = new String[3000];
        while (scanner.hasNext() && counter < 3000) {
            String word = scanner.next().toLowerCase();
            if (isAlpha(word) && word.length() > 0
                    && !checkOccurance(word, result)) {
                result[counter] = word;
                counter++;
            }

        }
        if (counter < 3000) {
            result = clean(result);
        }
        return result;

    }

    public static String[] clean(final String[] v) {
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(v));
        list.removeAll(Collections.singleton(null));
        return list.toArray(new String[list.size()]);
    }

    public static boolean isAlpha(String name) {
        char[] chars = name.toCharArray();

        for (char c : chars) {
            if (!Character.isLetter(c)) {
                return false;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }

    public static boolean checkOccurance(String word, String[] array) {

        for (String str : array)
            if (str != null) {
                if (str.equals(word))
                    return true;
            }
        return false;
    }

public static void printWords(String[] vocabulary,
        String firstLetter, String secondLetter, String thirdLetter){

    int counter=0;
    for (String str : vocabulary){
        int index1=0;
        int index2=0;
        int index3=0;

        if (str.contains(firstLetter))
            index1=str.indexOf(firstLetter);
        if ((str.substring(index1, str.length())).contains(secondLetter))
            index2=str.indexOf(secondLetter);
        if ((str.substring(index2, str.length())).contains(thirdLetter))
            index3=str.indexOf(thirdLetter);
        if (index3>index2 & index2>index1){
            System.out.println(str);
            counter++;
        }
        else
            System.out.println(index1 +"," + index2 +","+index3);

    }
    System.out.println("found "+ counter+" words");

}




public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException{
    File theFile = new File(args[0]);


    Scanner s = new Scanner(theFile);
    String[] wordslist = scanVocabulary(s);
    System.out.println("Read " +wordslist.length+" words from "+args[0]); //check if args[0] is ok
    System.out.println("Enter 3 letters or exit");
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    while (input.hasNextLine()) {
        String line = input.nextLine();
         if(line.equals("exit")) 
                break;

        if (line.length()!=5)
            System.out.println("[WARNING] Expecting 3 letters separated by one space");
         if (Character.isLetter(line.charAt(0)) && Character.isLetter(line.charAt(2)) && Character.isLetter(line.charAt(4)) )
             continue;
         else
             System.out.println("[WARNING] Expecting 3 letters separated by one space");

         String first = String.valueOf(line.charAt(0));
         String second = String.valueOf(line.charAt(2));
         String third = String.valueOf(line.charAt(4));

        printWords(wordslist,first,second,third);

    }
    input.close();

}

}
```

Comment: why continue is used in while loop after validity check

Comment: @VishalSantharam because if the input is ok I want the loop to continue and call printWords

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, why do you have to loop over a string and check if a character exists while you have many predefined methods that can do the job for, take a look at:

1. **[.contains() Method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains(java.lang.CharSequence))**
2. **[.indexOf() Method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf(int))**

Also it's better to use **[char.compareTo(char) method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#compareTo(java.lang.Character))** to compare two characters, so change this:

```
if (firstLetter.charAt(0)==letters[0])
```

with the following:

```
if (firstLetter.charAt(0).compareTo(letters[0]))
```

**EDIT:**

Change your test and directly compare indexof `firstletter`, indexof `secondletter` and index of `thirdletter` like this:

```
    if (str.contains(firstLetter)) {
        index1=str.indexOf(firstLetter);
        if (str.contains(secondLetter) && str.indexOf(secondLetter)>index1){
           index2=str.indexOf(secondLetter);
           if (str.contains(thirdLetter) && str.indexOf(thirdLetter)> index2)        {
               System.out.println(str);
               counter++;
           }
        }
    }
```

And note that the `AND` operator is `&&` in java instead of `&`.

**EDIT2:**

And to guarantee the search of an other occurence of a letter if it's inputted twice, you can replace the found letter with a `0`, this way if the next letter is the same, the first occurence will be removed and not found so you can get the next index if there's another occurence:

```
if (str.contains(firstLetter)) {
        index1=str.indexOf(firstLetter);
        str=str.substring(0,index1)+'0'+str.substring(index1+1);
        if (str.contains(secondLetter) && str.indexOf(secondLetter)>index1){
           index2=str.indexOf(secondLetter);
           str=str.substring(0,index2)+'0'+str.substring(index2+1);
           if (str.contains(thirdLetter) && str.indexOf(thirdLetter)> index2)        {
               System.out.println(str);
               counter++;
           }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I used your advise and used the two methods you mentioned. I still get an empty output! (I edited the code in my question)

Comment: @Tam211 Change your condition like the one in my EDIT.

Comment: The problem is that if a letter is inserted twice, I should check for two occurances for it. This code don't do this

Comment: @Tam211 take a look at my last edit this will garantee what you need.

Answer (score 0):

After input validity if check using continue makes the loop to look for next input , just remove it.

```
package sw1.ex4;

    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Arrays;
    import java.util.Collections;
    import java.util.List;
    import java.util.Scanner;

    public class WordSearch {
        public static String[] scanVocabulary(Scanner scanner) {

            int counter = 0;
            String[] result = new String[3000];
            while (scanner.hasNext() && counter < 3000) {
                String word = scanner.next().toLowerCase();
                if (isAlpha(word) && word.length() > 0
                        && !checkOccurance(word, result)) {
                    result[counter] = word;
                    counter++;
                }

            }
            if (counter < 3000) {
                result = clean(result);
            }
            return result;

        }

        public static String[] clean(final String[] v) {
            List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(v));
            list.removeAll(Collections.singleton(null));
            return list.toArray(new String[list.size()]);
        }

        public static boolean isAlpha(String name) {
            char[] chars = name.toCharArray();

            for (char c : chars) {
                if (!Character.isLetter(c)) {
                    return false;
                }
            }

            return true;
        }

        public static boolean checkOccurance(String word, String[] array) {

            for (String str : array)
                if (str != null) {
                    if (str.equals(word))
                        return true;
                }
            return false;
        }

        public static void printWords(String[] vocabulary,
                String firstLetter, String secondLetter, String thirdLetter){

            int counter=0;
            for (String str : vocabulary){
                char[] letters = str.toCharArray();
                int index2=0;
                int index3=0;
                if (firstLetter.charAt(0)==letters[0]){
                    for(int i=1; i<letters.length;i++){
                        if(secondLetter.charAt(0)==letters[i]){
                             index2 = i;
                        }
                        if(thirdLetter.charAt(0)==letters[i]){
                             index3 = i;
                        }

                    }
                    if (index2<index3){
                        counter++;
                        System.out.println(str);
                    }
                }

                continue;
            }
            System.out.println("found "+ counter+" words");

        }




    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException{
        File theFile = new File(args[0]);


        Scanner s = new Scanner(theFile);
        String[] wordslist = scanVocabulary(s);
        System.out.println("Read " +wordslist.length+" words from "+args[0]); //check if args[0] is ok
        System.out.println("Enter 3 letters or exit");
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        while (input.hasNextLine()) {
            String line = input.nextLine();
             if(line.equals("exit")) 
                    break;

            if (line.length()!=5)
                System.out.println("[WARNING] Expecting 3 letters separated by one space");
             if (Character.isLetter(line.charAt(0)) && Character.isLetter(line.charAt(2)) && Character.isLetter(line.charAt(4)) )
                 System.out.println("Valid Input :) ");
             else
                 System.out.println("[WARNING] Expecting 3 letters separated by one space");

             String first = String.valueOf(line.charAt(0));
             String second = String.valueOf(line.charAt(2));
             String third = String.valueOf(line.charAt(4));

            printWords(wordslist,first,second,third);

        }
        input.close();

    }

    }
```

Comment: Don't just paste code as an answer. Explain what you have done and how it helps the OP.

Answer (score 0):

My best guess is that `if (firstLetter.charAt(0)==letters[0]){` will never be true.

Try using the `.equals()` method.

Other comments: I would use the `.contains()` method rather than making a loop to scan a character at a time...

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You need to create some Singleton class which is responsible for your printing.

The idea is to have a static function for printing, when printing, the function will append the printed String to some ArrayList or either to StringBuffer which holds all the printed values.

Then you can implements some another static method to search what you need.

```
public class SystemPritingSingleton  {

    private static SystemPritingSingleton ins = null;
    private static StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

    private SystemPritingSingleton(){}

    private static SystemPritingSingleton getInstance(){

        if (ins == null){
            synchronized (SystemPritingSingleton.class) {
                if (ins == null){
                    ins = new SystemPritingSingleton();
                }   
            }           
        }
        return ins;
    }    

    public static void printMessage(String message){    
        getInstance();

        System.out.println(message);
        sb.append(message); 
    }       

    public static boolean searchMessage(String message){    
        getInstance();  
        return (sb.toString().indexOf(message) != -1);  
    }     
}
```

Usage:

```
public static void main (String[] args){
    String msg = "printMessage";
    SystemPritingSingleton.printMessage(msg);
    boolean isExist = SystemPritingSingleton.searchMessage(msg);
    .
    .       
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think in your `main` method `continue` statement is miplaced in

`if (Character.isLetter(line.charAt(0)) && Character.isLetter(line.charAt(2)) && Character.isLetter(line.charAt(4)) )
             continue;`

When this condition is satisfied you must call your `printWords` method, but continue statement executes and bypasses all statements below it including your `printWords` method statement that is why you are not getting any output.

you should call `printWords` method here:-

```
      if (Character.isLetter(line.charAt(0)) && Character.isLetter(line.charAt(2)) && Character.isLetter(line.charAt(4)) )
{
 String first = String.valueOf(line.charAt(0));
     String second = String.valueOf(line.charAt(2));
     String third = String.valueOf(line.charAt(4));

    printWords(wordslist,first,second,third);
}
```

Comment: seems i made mistake understanding your question, let me come up with a solution to that too.

Comment: @Tam211 check the edits, i think you misplaced your continue statement.

Comment: ignore grammatical mistakes  :-P